# Outputting combobox values to Excel from Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

I am trying to output the value of a combobox field in Access, as a string, to an Excel worksheet.

I tried several solutions/hacks and get 445 errors.

The combobox is a dropdown list of communities or populations served by the member (e.g. Gay men, Aging populations, Trans*, People of Colour, Aboriginal Groups, Women, New Canadians, etc.). Several can be selected and there are some blank records.

```vb
Sub OutputSub()
     ' Define a recordset for the Table I am using
     Dim myConnection As ADODB.Connection
     Set myConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
     Dim myRecordset As New ADODB.Recordset
     myRecordset.ActiveConnection = myConnection
     myRecordset.Open "MemberList", , adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic
     
     ' Open Excel and make a worksheet for me
     Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
     Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
     Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
     Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
     Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
     Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)
     ' Make Excel visible through the Application object.
     xlSheet.Application.Visible = True
     
     ' Variables for each of the values I will need
     Dim memCom As Variant, memServ As Variant, memLangs As Variant, memTot As Variant

     Dim memNum As Integer
     memNum = 2
     xlSheet.Application.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Services"
     
     'This loops through each of the records in the Table MemberList
     myRecordset.MoveFirst
     Do Until myRecordset.EOF()
        memCom = myRecordset.Fields("Communities Served")
        ' This next line causes a 1004 error, application or object defined error
        xlSheet.Application.Cells(memNum, 4).Value = memCom

        'Debug.Print memCom, memServ, memLangs
        
        memNum = memNum + 1
        myRecordset.MoveNext
     Loop
     
     ' Cleanup open files/variables, just in case
     myRecordset.Close
     Set myRecordset = Nothing
     Set myConnection = Nothing

End Sub
```

My goal is an Excel sheet with the values much like if I exported the DB as an Excel file. There are three previous columns of information I need in specific formats (which I have working, so I cut them out).

From StackOverflow I have found little information on how to access the value of the combobox, and lots of tips on how to add fields to the box.

UPDATE: The runtime error 1004: Application defined or object defined error happens as noted in the code as a comment.

UPDATE 2: Further digging has yielded this from the Office Dev Center: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f5de518d-a2f0-41b8-bfd3-155052547ab5/export-of-combo-box-to-excel-with-values-access-2010?forum=accessdev.
I created a query that will output the info I need with the memName, but I'm lost as to how to make it part of this output.

Comment: where is the error?  You can also use xlSheet.Application.Cells(1, 4)..CopyFromRecordset myRecordset

Comment: That solution (Copy from recordset) yields a type mismatch. (and I am now adding where the error occurs on the main entry)

Comment: xlSheet.Cells(1, 4).CopyFromRecordset myRecordset

Comment: Still giving a type mismatch

Comment: Can you check that RST is populated, xlSheet is the sheet req.

Comment: Sorry, noob here.... how do I check that? The other information that is being output by the same commands (but not from comboboxes) is printing correctly on the excel sheet.

Comment: put a breakpoint before the line, then hover over RST and see what's there, or interrogate in the immediate window, ? rst.recordcount

Comment: Recommended reading: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)

Comment: Is "Communities Served" a **multivalued** field? Then this might be more complicated.

Comment: Yes, it is multivalued. And I think that may be my problem. I am thinking a better solution is with a query to find the values, as per the update 2 link I provided above.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have discovered that the solution is to first query my combobox, then combine the results, then have it output to memCom. Once I have completed my new code, I will post my solution.

Comment: In case you are interested, this is the solution I came up with: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38084954/6523719

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the help from both @dbmitch and @Nathan_Sav, they helped me figure out what was wrong, so I could fix it.

For posterity sake, and for completion in case someone else has this issue, the solution was to make a query in Access for my multivalued combobox, and then make the value of that query into a recordset. Then I had to make a list of the values that the query returned, and then return that list into my excel sheet.

Here is my code:

```
Sub OutputSub()
 ' Define a recordset for the Table I am using
 Dim myConnection As ADODB.Connection
 Set myConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
 Dim myRecordset As New ADODB.Recordset
 myRecordset.ActiveConnection = myConnection
 myRecordset.Open "MemberList", , adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

 'Define a recordset for the query into my services
 Dim myConnection2 As ADODB.Connection
 Set myConnection2 = CurrentProject.Connection
 Dim myServicesRecordset As New ADODB.Recordset
 myServicesRecordset.ActiveConnection = myConnection2
 myServicesRecordset.Open "SELECT MemberList.[Organization Name], MemberList.[Services Offered].Value FROM MemberList", , adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic

 ' Open Excel and make a worksheet for me
 Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
 Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
 Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
 Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
 Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
 Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)
 ' Make Excel visible through the Application object.
 xlSheet.Application.Visible = True

 ' Variables for each of the values I will need
 Dim memName As String, memSite As Variant
 Dim memSoc As Variant, memNameHOLD
 Dim memServ As Variant, memServHOLD As Variant, memServName As Variant

 'Variable for the line in the database, and start it counting at 2, so there is space for Column headers
 ' Then give the column headers values.
 Dim memNum As Integer
 memNum = 2
 xlSheet.Application.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Member Name"
 xlSheet.Application.Cells(1, 4).Value = "Services"

 'This loops through each of the records in the Table MemberList
 myRecordset.MoveFirst
 Do Until myRecordset.EOF()
    ' Sets the value of the variables to the content of the relevant field
    memName = myRecordset.Fields("Organization Name")
    memSite = myRecordset.Fields("Website")

    'If there is content in the website field, then make the Org Name a link, else leave it as is.
    If Not IsNull(memSite) Then
        memNameHOLD = "<a href=" & memSite & ">" & memName & "</a>"
    Else
        memNameHOLD = memName
    End If

    'Collect the Services offered into a list for this memName
    myServicesRecordset.MoveFirst
    Do Until myServicesRecordset.EOF()
        memServ = myServicesRecordset.Fields(1)
        memServName = myServicesRecordset.Fields(0)
        If memServName = memName Then
            memServHOLD = memServHOLD & memServ & ", "
        Else
            memServHOLD = memServHOLD
        End If
        myServicesRecordset.MoveNext
        memServ = ""
    Loop

    xlSheet.Application.Cells(memNum, 1).Value = memNameHOLD
    xlSheet.Application.Cells(memNum, 3).Value = memRegion

    xlSheet.Cells(memNum, 4).Value = "Services Offered: " & memServHOLD

    memNum = memNum + 1
    myRecordset.MoveNext
    'Clear the hold value
    memServHOLD = ""
 Loop

 ' Cleanup open files/variables, just in case
 myRecordset.Close
 Set myRecordset = Nothing
 Set myConnection = Nothing
End Sub
```

The keen eye may still be able to tell me why there is a `,` in the output if there were no values. But all things considered, that small comma is an acceptable error.

Answer (score 0):

If you step through your program what line causes the error - that's the first step to troubleshooting

What is the value coming out of the field `"Communities Served"` ? Is it a comma delimited string that you want split into multiple columns - or just to fill the once cell with whatever comes out - that's what it looks like to me?

In any case, get rid of your error by changing

```
xlSheet.Application.Cells(memNum, 4).Value = memCom
```

to

```
xlSheet.Cells(memNum, 4).Value = memCom
```

> EDIT - memCom is coming back as a array Use  Debug Watch to look at
>   how you need to access the value - probably even as simple as
>   memcon(0)

Comment: Thanks, but this still yields the same error. Also, the working lines (in code not shown) have the same `xlsheet.Application.Cells` and they have no errors in them.

Comment: So... as I asked ... what line is causing the error?

Comment: Add a Debug.Print on memCom after it's assigned. Or even better put a breakpoint on the error line , and then add a watch on memcom to view the contents

Comment: Sorry, I added a new comment to the code in the original post, and forgot to tell you.... I don't know how to step through, but when it fails, the debugger highlights this line `xlSheet.Application.Cells(memNum, 4).Value = memCom`

Comment: And the locals window tells me that memCom has `<No variables>` despite being a variant/object type

Comment: I've also tried using `memCom.Value`, but apparently the object "doesn't support this action"

Comment: If your watch window shows memCom - there should be a "+" sign to expand it. If there isn't add a Watch to see if anything is being returned from `myRecordset.Fields("Communities Served")`

Comment: Using the watch gets me the same information as the locals window: memCom is a Variant/Object, and has a value <no variables>

Comment: I repeat - add the watch to look at `myRecordset.Fields("Communities Served")` - it looks like nothing is being returned from your recordset - you can even widen the watch by looking at `myRecordset`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have discovered that the solution is to first query my combobox, then combine the results, then have it output to memCom. Once I have completed my new code, I will post my solution.

Comment: In case you are interested, this is the solution I came up with: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38084954/6523719